# How much time would Voldemort have lived if Harry didn't destroy the Horcruxes?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux

In the book Voldemort created several Horcruxes which supposedly if undiscovered would make him immortal.
However, wouldn't it only mean that he would live approximately 1000 years?

Wizards live pretty long lives when compared to Muggles so I am assuming he would live 150 years before dying from old age. And also assuming after each "rebirth" his age would restart at 0.

However, I am not sure how the age is determined when you are resurrected via a Horcrux. Maybe by which age you were at the time of the creation of the Horcrux?

Comment: I think you're operating under the assumption that if he is "killed" or dies that one of the horcruxes is destroyed as well. I see no reason from what is present in the books to believe that to be the case.

Comment: Aren't the Horcruxes like additional life points? Meaning when you die you spend one Horcrux the get resurrected ?

Comment: Nope. Not sure where you got that idea from.

Comment: Where are you getting 150 years?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## He will not die if any Horcruxes remain.

A Horcrux is a permanent tie to life unless it is destroyed. It does not provide a new body, so Voldemort would need to create a new body each time his old one dies, but he would remain immortal as long as at least one Horcrux existed tying him to life.

> “Well, you split your soul, you see,’ said Slughorn, ‘and hide part of it in an object outside the body. Then, even if one’s body is attacked or destroyed, one cannot die, for part of the soul remains earthbound and undamaged. But, of course, existence in such a form …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 23 (Horcruxes)*</sup></sub>

They are not used up if their creator’s body is killed - Dumbledore explained to Harry that all of Voldemort’s Horcruxes must be destroyed before any attempt to kill the piece of soul that lives in his body.

> “I am glad to see you appreciate the magnitude of the problem,’ said Dumbledore calmly. ‘But firstly, no, Harry, not seven Horcruxes: six. The seventh part of his soul, however maimed, resides inside his regenerated body. That was the part of him that lived a spectral existence for so many years during his exile; without that, he has no self at all. That seventh piece of soul will be the last that anybody wishing to kill Voldemort must attack – the piece that lives in his body.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 23 (Horcruxes)*</sup></sub>

When his body died at the Potters’ house, the piece of soul in it indeed did not die, but became bodiless.

> “*He pointed the wand very carefully into the boy’s face: he wanted to see it happen, the destruction of this one, inexplicable danger. The child began to cry: it had seen that he was not James. He did not like it crying, he had never been able to stomach the small ones’ whining in the orphanage –*
>
> ‘Avada Kedavra!’
>
> *And then he broke: he was nothing, nothing but pain and terror, and he must hide himself, not here in the rubble of the ruined house, where the child was trapped and screaming, but far away … far away …”* 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 17 (Bathilda’s Secret)*</sup></sub>

When recounting the experience to the Death Eaters, Voldemort described it as being ripped from his body.

> “I was ripped from my body, I was less than spirit, less than the meanest ghost … but still, I was alive. What I was, even I do not know … I, who have gone further than anybody along the path that leads to immortality. You know my goal – to conquer death. And now, I was tested, and it appeared that one or more of my experiments had worked … for I had not been killed, though the curse should have done it.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33 (The Death Eaters)*</sup></sub>

The soul fragment that existed in Voldemort’s body was not killed when his body was, and no Horcrux was used up when his body died at the Potters’ house.

Comment: when his body will die the wouldn't the 1/7 of his soul that was present in that body also be destroyed and the other 1/7 that was in a horcrux be "unleashed" ?

Comment: Well, until such time as the horcruxes are destroyed. One assumes that would happen [*eventually*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe)

Comment: Nope: the soul never „dies“ if the body does. After his first „death“ through his own Avada Kedavra that part of his soul still lived on and searched for a new body... you don‘t „use up“ Horcruxes: their existance is enough for you to not die. Thats why one Horcrux is totally enough to live forever, as long as you hide it well enough...

Comment: one would also have to assume that the body he built (wormtail built) in GOF is more sturdy than the standard human body. it may not be susceptible to human ailments

Comment: the fact that he can build a body leads me down the line of thought that every time a current body got old he would just transfer his prime soul bit into a new body. whether he had to kill himself or could voluntarily posses another body at that point is unknown.